# Parse complex json in airflow using python

Tags: python, airflow, directed-acyclic-graphs

Below given is my json.

```
{
  "configuration": [
{
  "task_name":"reading",
  "novel":{
    "name":"ABC",
    "author":"aut1"
  },
  "story":{
    "name":"CDE",
    "author":"aut2"
  }
},
{
  "task_name":"singing",
  "pop":{
    "name":"rockit",
    "author":"aut11"
  },
  "jazz":{
    "name":"jazzy",
    "author":"aut22"
  }
}
  ]
}
```

I want to read this json from admin variables in airflow then based on condition(task_name) need to iterate through it and takeout values and assign to variables.

Since i am new in airflow and python it found difficult to get answer.
Welcomes any inputs

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Follow these steps:

1. Create your admin variable. Put your JSON in plain text in the `Val` value and specify a `Key` (e.g. "configuration").
2. Import the `Variable` model in your Python code.

```
from airflow.models import Variable
```

3. Get your admin var using the `Variable` model and deserialize it to a Python `dict` setting `deserialize_json` to `True`.

```
configs = Variable.get("configuration", deserialize_json=True)
```

4. Now you can iterate it like a regular `dict`.

```
for config in configs["configuration"]:
    print(config["task_name"])
```